# How to Import JSON file and cast it

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript

I load a JSON file in react with an import statement like below :

```
import myStrings from './date.json';
```

The JSON structure is very simple :

```
[
   {
       "type": 1,
       "text": "mytext",
       "during": 5,
   }
]
```

Now I don't find any way to cast an item of this collection, to use in a function parameter. I don't want to use an any type :

```
const ret = myFunction(myStrings[0]); 

const myFunction = (astringParameter:any):string => { ... }
```

How to cast this item?

Comment: what exactly is your problem here? TS should be able to infer the type of `myStrings`

Comment: "I don't want to use any type"... why use **Type**Script then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an interface like this.

```
interface MyString {
  type: number,
  text: string,
  during": number,
}
```

```
const ret: MyString = myFunction(myStrings[0]); 

const myFunction = (astringParameter:MyString):string => { ... }
```